# LIMIT showing duplicate results

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out why this is happening.  I have a table with the following columns:

```
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| adid        | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| price       | float      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| categoryid  | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| visible     | tinyint(4) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

There are 7 records in this table that are visible and have category set as 3.  I do a simple query like this:

```
SELECT adid FROM ads as a 
WHERE categoryid = 3 
and visible = 1 
order by price desc 
limit 0, 5
```

I get the following adid's returned: 1,4,3,15,7

On the next page the query is:

```
SELECT adid FROM ads as a 
WHERE categoryid = 3 
and visible = 1 
order by price desc 
limit 5, 5
```

I get: 11,15

Maybe I am up too late, but why do I get 15 twice?

Comment: do they have the same `price` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the results to be stable and consistent you need to have any unique column to participate in sorting.

In this case it might be

```
ORDER BY price DESC, adid
```

Comment: Thank you.  I forgot all about that caveat.  Will mark accepted as soon as the time limit is over.